# fill password field causing pressButton to fail in Zombie.js

Tags: testing, coffeescript, zombie.js

I am trying to write client-side tests with Zombie.js (http://zombie.labnotes.org/) in CoffeeScript, and mocha.  Currently, I just want to fill in a login form and submit it, but am running into a problem.  When I fill out the username field and press the login button, the pressButton callback is being fired, although the the login is not successful (as desired).  However, when I fill out the username and password field before pressing the login button, the pressButton callback is not being fired.  Here is my example where the callback is not fired:

```
browser.visit "#{APP_ROOT}/login", ->
  browser
    .fill('username', 'testuser')
    .fill('password', 'password')
    .pressButton 'Log In', ->
      # this is never called
      done()
```

Without filling in the password field, the callback is fired:

```
browser.visit "#{APP_ROOT}/login", ->
  browser
    .fill('username', 'testuser')
    .pressButton 'Log In', ->
      # However, this IS called
      done()
```

Comment: any js firing off when the password input is filled in? wild guess here

Comment: No JS on the page in this case.

Comment: try use css selector instead of text : `.fill('#password', 'password')`. 
Plus, you may add `browser.debug = true;` and get more verbose things.